# Extract value from Json using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson, wunderground

I am trying to extract values from JSON from the URL provided below using GSON java library:
http://api.wunderground.com/api/b28d047ca410515a/forecast/q/-33.912,151.013.json

I have successfully used the code provided below to extract data from URL below: 
http://api.wunderground.com/api/b28d047ca410515a/conditions/q/-33.912,151.013.json

Code:

```
   String url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/b28d047ca410515a/conditions/q/-33.912,151.013.json";
   String url2 = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/b28d047ca410515a/forecast/q/-33.912,151.013.json";

            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                is = new URL(url).openStream();
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                String jsonText = readAll(rd);

                JsonElement je = new JsonParser().parse(jsonText);

                System.out.println("Current Temperature:" + getAtPath(je, "current_observation/temp_c").getAsString() );


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {
                try {
                    if (is != null)
                        is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

However I am getting exception trying to extract from url2 as per code below , it seems to be a more complicated json to get values from, any help please?

```
// below code not working

            weather_icon_url = getAtPath(je, "current_observation/icon_url").getAsString();

            is = new URL(url2).openStream();
            BufferedReader rd2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            String jsonText2 = readAll(rd2);

            JsonElement je2 = new JsonParser().parse(jsonText2);

            System.out.println("max Temperature:" + getAtPath(je2, "forecast/simpleforecast/forecastday/high/celsius").getAsString() );

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            try {
                if (is != null)
                    is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

getAtPath code:

```
private static JsonElement getAtPath(JsonElement e, String path) {
        JsonElement current = e;
        String ss[] = path.split("/");
        for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
            current = current.getAsJsonObject().get(ss[i]);
        }
        return current;
    }
```

Comment: What exception are you getting? Please provide the implementation of `getAtPath`.

Comment: I get the following exception: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: [{"date":{"epoch":"1459152000","...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because there is an issue with the `getAtPath` implementation.

`[{"date":{"epoch":"1459152000"...` represents a JSONArray which the method is trying to access as JSONObject. Hence the `IllegalStateException`.

> JsonObject com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonObject()
>
> convenience method to get this element as a JsonObject. If the element
>   is of some other type, a IllegalStateException will result. Hence it
>   is best to use this method after ensuring that this element is of the
>   desired type by calling isJsonObject() first.

You can update and use something like below, as of now it returns only the first element.

```
    private static JsonElement getAtPath(JsonElement e, String path) {
        JsonElement current = e;
        String ss[] = path.split("/");
        for (int i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
            if(current instanceof JsonObject){
                current = current.getAsJsonObject().get(ss[i]);
            } else if(current instanceof JsonArray){
                JsonElement jsonElement = current.getAsJsonArray().get(0);
                current = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get(ss[i]);
            }
        }
        return current;
    }
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to accept the answer :P

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
System.out.println("max Temperature:" + getAtPath(je2, "forecast/simpleforecast/forecastday/high/celsius").getAsString() );
```

Comment: not working, it is throwing the following exception: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: [{"date":{"epoch":"1459152000","...........

Comment: That is because the JSON returned is actually an array. Can you post getAtPath method as well?